# SELECT mysql column with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

Consider I have a table like this.

```
+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
+     id      +    column 1   +    column 2    +    column 3   +
+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+ 
+      1      +     values    +     values     + a, b, c, d, e +  
+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```

My query can be like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = 'values' AND column 3 = '$variable'
```

The $variable can be anything from a to e

Is there a way to use query to select the row the I want?

Comment: Smells like bad database architecture.

Comment: You'll need to use a like clause.

Comment: If it's legacy code in enterprise, it may be complicated to change the database structure, but if you want to query a subset of a field, yoy may consider to split the fourth column (3) into many others, on in many associations.

Comment: @PLB Thanks bro. It's just for sample

Comment: @BillyONeal I thought so. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy I really don't want to split into many columns, I my find another solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()` -- a builtin function for mysql to search a string

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE column 1 = 'values' and  FIND_IN_SET('a',column 3 )>0
```

- [sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4023/48)
- [REFER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample one like my query

Comment: for what you are using > 0 after the FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() return position of  string , > 0 means it present in the list or not(refer link)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('$variable', column 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql function find_in_set can search only for one string in a set of strings. the first argument is a string, so there is no way to make it parse your comma separated string into strings (you can't use commas in SET elements at all!). the second argument is a SET, which in turn is represented by a comma separated string hence your wish to find_in_set('a,b,c', 'a,b,c,d') which works fine, but it surely can't find a string 'a,b,c' in any SET by definition - it contains commas.

> SELECT  * FROM    tableName WHERE column 1 = 'values' and 
>   FIND_IN_SET('a',column3 )

Answer (score 1):

use this query select * from table where column 1 = 'values' AND column 3 like '%$value%'

Comment: Thanks for help mate. I think I can use FIND_IN_SET will be better for my case